# Javascript, Jquery, HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i add prevent-default() with focus-out() in my form. I face problem when i click the reset button in my form. It show the last focusing input field error message when i click the reset button. Here my code bellow:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //error message section:
    $("#username_error_msg").hide();
    $("#gender_Select_error_msg").hide();
    $("#jobCategory_error_msg").hide();
    $("#experience_sector_error_msg").hide();
    $("#password_error_msg").hide();
    $("#retype_password_error_msg").hide();
    $("#email_error_msg").hide();
    $("#phone_no_error_msg").hide();
    $("#short_note_error_msg").hide();

    //username validation area:
    function checkUsername(){
        var name = $("#username").val();
        var usernameLength = $("#username").val().length;
        if(!name.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
            $("#username_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Username shouldn't be empty..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else if(usernameLength < 5 || usernameLength > 20){
            $("#username_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Username should be between 5-20 characters..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $("#username_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Gender selection check:
    function checkGenderSelection(){
        var genderCategory = $('select[name=Gender]').val();
        if(genderCategory == 'Select'){
            $("#gender_Select_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Please select your gender..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else if((genderCategory == 'Male') || (genderCategory == 'Female')){
            $("#gender_Select_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //job category check: radiobutton
    function checkJobCategorySelection(){
        var jobCategory = $('input[name=jobCategory]:checked');
        if(jobCategory.length == 0){
            $("#jobCategory_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>No Category Selected..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $("#jobCategory_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
                            //By this way we can collect the value from radio button for further action//
            //console.log("Selected Item: " + jobCategory.val());
        }
    }

    //programming Experience check: checkbox
    function programmingExperienceCheck(){
        var experienceList = $('input:checkbox[name=language]:checked');
        if(experienceList.length == 0){
            $("#experience_sector_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>No Sector Selected..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $("#experience_sector_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //password validation area:
    function checkPassword(){
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        var passwordLength = $("#password").val().length;
        if(!pass.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
            $("#password_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Please type your password..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else if(passwordLength < 8){
            $("#password_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Password should be minimum 8 characters..!<span class='errorMessage'>").slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $("#password_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //retype password validation area:
    function checkRetypePassword(){
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        var retypePass = $("#retype_password").val();
        if(!retypePass.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
            $("#retype_password_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Please give your password again..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }
        else if(pass !== retypePass){
            $("#retype_password_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Password don't match..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $("#retype_password_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //email validation area:
    function checkEmail(){
        var regularExp = new RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})/);
        if(!$("#email").val().replace(/\s/g, '').length){
            $("#email_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Please give your email id..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }
        else if(regularExp.test($("#email").val())){
            $("#email_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }else{
            $("#email_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Invalid Email..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }
    }

    //phone number validation area:
    function checkPhoneNumber(){
        var phone_number = $("#phoneNo").val();
        var regularExp = new RegExp(/^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$/);
        if(!phone_number.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
            $("#phone_no_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Please enter a phone number..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else if(regularExp.test($("#phoneNo").val())){
            $("#phone_no_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }else{
            $("#phone_no_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Invalid phone number..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }
    }

    //short notes validation area:
    function checkShortNotes(){
        var shortNotes = $("#short_note").val();
        var shortNotesLength = $("#short_note").val().length;
        if(!shortNotes.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
            $("#short_note_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>You have to write something about you..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else if(shortNotesLength < 10){
            $("#short_note_error_msg").html("<span class='errorMessage'>Your notes is too short..!</span>").slideDown(500);
        }else{
            $("#short_note_error_msg").slideUp(500);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //username focus action:
    $("#username").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)){
            checkUsername();
        }
    });

    //gender focus action:
    $("#gender").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)) {
            checkGenderSelection();
        }
    });

    //password focus action:
    $("#password").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)) {
            checkPassword();
        }
    });

    //retypePassword focus action:
    $("#retype_password").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)) {
            checkRetypePassword();
        }
    });

    //email focus action:
    $("#email").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)) {
            checkEmail();
        }
    });

    //phone number focus action:
    $("#phoneNo").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)) {
            checkPhoneNumber();
        }
    });

    //shortNotes focus action:
    $("#short_note").focusout(function(){
        if($('input[type=reset]').data('clicked',false)) {
            checkShortNotes();
        }
    });

    //form submit action:
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){

        if(checkUsername() && checkGenderSelection() && checkJobCategorySelection() && programmingExperienceCheck() && checkPassword() && checkRetypePassword() && checkEmail() && checkPhoneNumber() && checkShortNotes()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });
});

//refresh button action:
$('input[type=reset]').click(function(){
    $("#username_error_msg").hide();
    $("#gender_Select_error_msg").hide();
    $("#jobCategory_error_msg").hide();
    $("#experience_sector_error_msg").hide();
    $("#password_error_msg").hide();
    $("#retype_password_error_msg").hide();
    $("#email_error_msg").hide();
    $("#phone_no_error_msg").hide();
    $("#short_note_error_msg").hide();
});
```

```css
.errorMessage{background-color: darkcyan;color:white; border-radius:2px;font-size: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" action="msg.php" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="username"></td>
                            <td><span id="username_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Select Your Gender: </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="Gender" id="gender">
                                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="gender_Select_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Select Job Category: </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="radio" name="jobCategory" value="Part Time"/> Part Time
                                <input type="radio" name="jobCategory" value="Full Time"/> Full Time
                                <input type="radio" name="jobCategory" value="Intern"/> Intern
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="jobCategory_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Select Experience Sector:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language"/> Javascript
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language"/> PHP
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language"/> Jquery
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="experience_sector_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Password: </td>
                            <td><input type="password" id="password"></td>
                            <td><span id="password_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Retype Password: </td>
                            <td><input type="password" id="retype_password"></td>
                            <td><span id="retype_password_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Email: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
                            <td><span id="email_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Phone No: </td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="phoneNo"></td>
                            <td><span id="phone_no_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Short Note About You: </td>
                            <td><textarea id="short_note" cols="22" rows="5"></textarea></td>
                            <td><span id="short_note_error_msg"></span></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                <input type="reset" value="Refresh"/>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

});

How can i stop to seeing any focus-out() action when i click reset button????

Comment: Add only the relavant code which is causing the issue

Comment: dear my full code is here, when i click the reset button it create problem that last pointing(mouse pointer) input field show its error message if it is empty which i create in the checkFunction() for all input field.....Hope you get this point.

Answer (score 0):

When you reset the form, you are hiding all the error messages. Then focus on the first element - username.

```
    //refresh button action:
    $('input[type=reset]').click(function(){
        $("#username_error_msg").hide();
        $("#gender_Select_error_msg").hide();
        $("#jobCategory_error_msg").hide();
        $("#experience_sector_error_msg").hide();
        $("#password_error_msg").hide();
        $("#retype_password_error_msg").hide();
        $("#email_error_msg").hide();
        $("#phone_no_error_msg").hide();
        $("#short_note_error_msg").hide();

        $('#username').focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Blur comes before click so you are setting the `.html` of the error, then the click comes and you hide it but because you use `.slide` jQuery will then set it visible again as it's sliding in.

The simplest way would be to set the html of the error to an empty string, jQuery can then slide in an empty string:

```
function removeErrors(){
  $("#username_error_msg").html("");
  $("#gender_Select_error_msg").html("");
  $("#jobCategory_error_msg").html("");
  $("#experience_sector_error_msg").html("");
  $("#password_error_msg").html("");
  $("#retype_password_error_msg").html("");
  $("#email_error_msg").html("");
  $("#phone_no_error_msg").html("");
  $("#short_note_error_msg").html("");
}
//refresh button action:
$('input[type=reset]').click(function(){
  removeErrors();
});
```